# How to correctly 2-way-bind with reactive forms?

Tags: angular, 2-way-object-databinding, angular-reactive-forms

So far I've always seen that you shouldn't mix using `[(ngModel)]` with reactive forms, and instead simply use `formControlName`.

However, for me it doesn't seem to be working?

I have a form and I add controls to it

```
this.exportForm.addControl("surcharge", new FormControl(this.details.SurchargeExtraField));
```

and in my html I give the input the `formControlName`

```
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <input type="text" formControlName="surcharge" />
    </div>
```

However when I use the input it doesn't change anything about `this.details.SurchargeExtraField`, it only works for validation.

When I do:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="surcharge" [(ngModel)]="details.SurchargeExtraField" />
```

It works perfectly, but appareantly it's not the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the form changes by using this

```
  this.exportForm.valueChanges.subscribe((form) => {
     console.log(form);
   });
```

For more info on reactive form check this [**LINK**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/reactive)

The same is applicable for any **FormControl** in the form you can look for changes and act accordingly

Comment: so "automatic" 2-way-binding like `[(ngModel)]` does is not possible with reactive forms?

Comment: you get the binding done if you see that example link the form is getting updated dynamically  but it is not like ngModel but using observables on formControl

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for form changes like this

```
this.exportForm.valueChanges.subscribe((changes) => {
     console.log(changes);
});
```

or you can listen for formcontrol changes like this

```
this.exportForm.get('surcharge').valueChanges.subscribe((change) => {
     console.log(change);
});
```

or you can do this

```
onChange (newVal) {
   console.log(newVal);
}

<input type="text" formControlName="surcharge" #surchargeInput (change)="onChange(surcharge.target.value)"/>
```

Comment: "there's no reason to not mix formControlName and ngModel like this" - Except the fact that behavior is deprecated in Angular 6, and will be gone in Angular 7.

Comment: You are completely right, but at the time I answered it was possible. So I'm gonna edit my answer now.