# Do Angular Reactive Forms handle undefined values inconsistently?

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angular-forms

**TL,DR;**

Undefined values behave differently depending on the method of achieving two-way binding in [Angular Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). Please see [this StackBlitz](https://angular-jzpqfz.stackblitz.io) for a demo.

[image]

**Detail**

The SO Question, [How to correctly 2-way-bind with reactive forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46090554/how-to-correctly-2-way-bind-with-reactive-forms), [received an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46090822/828547) stating...

> there's no reason to not mix formControlName and ngModel

Firstly, is [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46090822/828547) a valid way to achieve two-way data binding?

Secondly, can someone clarify the difference in behaviour of undefined values in [Angular Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)? I've [created a StackBlitz](https://angular-jzpqfz.stackblitz.io) for this question.

The main HTML form mutates the component's underlying data, `attributes`:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public form: FormGroup;

  // title and subtitle will be undefined.
  public attributes = {};

  constructor(private readonly fb: FormBuilder) { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {

    // This is OK, I want title and subtitle to be undefined.
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      title: this.attributes.title,
      subtitle: this.attributes.subtitle
    });
  }
}
```

The `form: FormGroup` defines two `<input>` and `<button>` pairs; one for `attributes.title`, another for `attributes.subtitle`.

The first `<input>` uses `[(ngModel)]` - binding to the underlying model with a **template driven** approach within **reactive form**:

```
<!-- Title uses [(ngModel)] for 2-way binding. -->

<input formControlName="title"
       [(ngModel)]="attributes.title">

<button (click)="undefineTitle()">Undefine title</button>
```

The `<button>` simply sets `attributes.title` to **undefined**:

```
public undefineTitle() {
    this.attributes.title = undefined;
}
```

The second `<input>` uses `[value]` and `(input)` rather than `[(ngModel)]` for data-binding:

```
<!-- Subtitle uses [value] and (input) for 2-way binding. -->

<input formControlName="subtitle"
       [value]="getValue()"
       (input)="setValue($event.target.value)">

<button (click)="undefineSubtitle()">Undefine subtitle</button>
```

The `<button>` simply sets `attributes.subtitle` to **undefined**:

```
public undefineSubtitle() {
    this.attributes.subtitle = undefined;
}
```

Since `attributes.subtitle` is modified using `[value]` and `(input)` rather than `[(ngModel)]`, two simple event handlers are defined in the component:

```
/* Handlers for 2-way binding of subtitle */
public getValue(): string {
    return this.attributes.subtitle;
}

public setValue(s: string) {
    this.attributes.subtitle = s;
}
```

The `<input>` element shows `undefined` for **subtitle**, whereas **title** seems to handler this better (IMO) and displays nothing?

Upon page-load, you can see the problem immediately since neither `title` nor `subtitle` are defined when the `form: FormGroup` is created:

[image]

As expected, two-way data-binding works:

[image]

...and empty values behave the same:

[image]

Comment: You're using template-driven ngModel field. These aren't reactive forms.

Comment: So to achieve two-way binding with reactive forms, separate `[value]` and `(input)` directives must be used?

Comment: I mean that these are 'regular' forms, not reactive. The answer may be different for those two. Reactive are those where form controls are used.

Comment: With reactive form, you just need `formControlName` (wrapped by some `[formGroup]`), and two-way bindings will be created. Scrap all `[value]`, `(input)` and `[(ngModel)]`.

Comment: @harry-ninh - Unfortunately the value must be written to a different part of the model depending on the value of a select-menu. I must capture the input, check a variable, and write to the appropriate part of the model.

Comment: Do subscribe to `valueChanges` event in your component class and all will be sorted.